Cause of Displacement Current
What causes displacement current ?
[How does varying electric field produce current ?]

Why do you think they are not real?

But, more importantly, all science courses come in layers. Each course should start with some variation of: "All that stuff we taught you last semester? Well, it is more complicated than that..."

I don't know what causes them, so i think that

Displacement current is not a current like the current through a resistor on a batterie.

I understand that, what you talk about is conduction current.

I’m voting to close this question because the question of whether something is "real" or "truly exists" is about ontology and not physics.

Drastically editing questions after someone has answered an earlier version is considered very bad behavior on SE generally.

Honestly many things in nature don't necessarily have the deeper 'why'. Why does quantum mechanics work? Why are there some kind of elementary particles and not the others? Why are the fundamental constants the way they are? Sometimes it turns out that we can find a deeper reason, but in principle, philosophically, there is no reason that something is true. It could true just because it is.
The displacement current is definitely real in the sense that it correctly helps to describe the electromagnetic phenomena. Without it, electromagnetism would sometimes give wrong answers. In fact, more dramatically, Maxwell's theory would be mathematically inconsistent! That is, the equations would contradict each other and no sensible prediction could be made.
It is tricky to explain the contradiction without vector calculus, but the key idea is that by taking the divergence of the Ampere's law and substituting the Gauss's law one would obtain a continuity equation for conservation of electric charge. Without the displacement term the theory would imply that electric currents can vanish and appear out of nothing.
A particular physical system that illustrates the necessity for the displacement current is a capacitor. Imagine its two plates connected to two long wires (which can be connected to a power source far away). As the current flows in the wires, a circular magnetic field is created around the wire and the capacitor. The magnetic field around the wire can be found from the Ampere's law. But what happens in between the capacitor's plates? There is no current flowing, yet the magnetic field cannot abruptly go to zero as we move along the setup from the wire to the space in between the capacitors. The answer is that as the current flows, the capacitor's plates charge, leading to a steady growth of the electric field in between the plates. The rate of change of this field corresponds exactly to the displacement current which creates the magnetic field in between the plates.
I hope this helps.

so energy conservation ? well then i guess its the best answer i have got.

not energy but electric charge

Displacement current is not the kind of current you have in a circuit, with batterie and resistor. in this sense it's not a real current, It has the dimension of a current and is defined as changing of E over time.

It is not the motion of charged particles, so indeed the name current could be a bit inappropriate. It does, however, arise in all kinds of systems including circuits with a battery and resitor. It occurs whenever the electric field changes in time.

starting to make sense now

The entity that Maxwell referred to as 'displacement current' is real in the sense of being indispensible. At the same time: it isn't necessary to be committed as to what 'displacement current' is. The most cautious attitude is to regard it as something that must be granted in order to be able to formulate the theory (in Maxwell's form) at all.
Kevin Brown in a discussion of Maxwell's displacement current, makes the following suggestion:

[...] to the three common justifications for the displacement current discussed above, we might add a fourth, namely, the fact that the inclusion of the term $\partial E/\partial t$ in Ampere’s equation leads to transverse electromagnetic waves propagating in a vacuum at the speed of light. Of course, this is ordinarily presented (triumphantly) as a consequence of the added term, rather than as a justification or motivation for it. However, someone as mathematically astute as Maxwell could hardly have failed to notice that the standard wave equation would result from the known system of electromagnetic equations if only Ampere’s law contained a term of the form $\partial E/\partial t$


Again: even with a cautious deferring of any commitment as to what displacement current is, it must be regarded as being as real as the other components of propagation of electromagnetic waves.

so what is its cause ?

should we simply accept it as it makes equations work ?

i feel like i am not able to grasp your answer, i feel that you justify the existence of displacement current, which now i have understood, the cause is what bothers me, from the other answer i could think of it as energy conservation
